# Java :: How to import the Excel File Stored in Google Drive to a specific Google Spreadsheet

Tags: java, excel, google-drive-api, google-sheets-api

I have a use case where I need to upload the Excel file programmatically to Google Drive and import that into the existing blank Google Spreadsheet using Java.

The Google Spreadsheet is getting created programmatically and I need to import the existing excel file present in Google Drive to the already created google spreadsheet using the Spreadsheet ID.

I have gone through different documentations but was unable to find an example or any support for the same.

Please suggest.

Comment: https://developers.google.com/sheets/api/reference/rest/v4/spreadsheets.sheets/copyTo

Comment: Thanks, I went through this documentation but is there any way to fetch the Google Docs "Spreadsheet ID" of the file present in Google Drive (Not the File ID)?

Comment: A sheet id is a file id its the same thing.  use the try me on the page https://developers.google.com/sheets/api/reference/rest/v4/spreadsheets/get just use your fileid from google drive to test it.

Comment: Thanks, yes I tested, it works for files that are already converted to google spreadsheet format but didn't work for Excel files, that means while uploading it is needed to programmatically convert the excel files into Google Spreadsheet format, is there a way to convert the excel file to google spreadsheet format while uploading to google drive?

Comment: Google drive v2 has an optional parameter to covert the file to drive format when the file is uploaded called convert.  drive v3 requires that you send a mimetype to covert it.  Which version of the Google drive api are you working with currently?    can you check your tagging on the question please are you doing this with java or app scripts?

Comment: Thanks for the answer, I am doing this with Java, I have updated the taggings, I am using version 3. I am working on your answer, but getting error with "File fileMetadata = new File();" due to missing jars, I have included the Google Drive Service api jar and other corresponding dependencies too, if you know the exact jar please let me know, I will update here if I get it

Comment: I fixed that issue, it was due to collision in imports, but still getting error for this: FileContent mediaContent = new FileContent("text/csv", filePath); The message is : FileContent cannot be resolved to a type

Comment: that's probably because of the FileContent("text/csv",   need to figure out what the content is if its an excel file.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When the file is uploaded to google drive you need to set the mime type for it to convert the file automatically.  [Importing to Google Docs types](https://developers.google.com/drive/v3/web/manage-uploads#importing_to_google_docs_types_wzxhzdk8wzxhzdk9)

```
File fileMetadata = new File();
fileMetadata.setName("My Report");
fileMetadata.setMimeType("application/vnd.google-apps.spreadsheet");

java.io.File filePath = new java.io.File("files/report.csv");
FileContent mediaContent = new FileContent("text/csv", filePath);
File file = driveService.files().create(fileMetadata, mediaContent)
        .setFields("id")
        .execute();
System.out.println("File ID: " + file.getId());
```

Assuming that the file is a google sheet then a google drive file id is also a google sheet id.  so you will be able to access it in [Method: spreadsheets.sheets.copyTo](https://developers.google.com/sheets/api/reference/rest/v4/spreadsheets.sheets/copyTo)

Comment: Thanks! I got it working with Excel files by replacing "text/csv" with "application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.spreadsheetml.sheet" in the FileContent